# How to Oauth Get Access Token with No Expiry in Google Dialogue flow API

Tags: google-oauth, dialogflow-es

Normally Google Access token is valid for one hour but I want to set it to no expiry. How can I do that, please help

Answer (score 1):

Google access tokens are only good for one hour this is Oauth2 standard and can not be changed.   You will need to use a refresh token to request a new access token.   No idea if that is possible with dialogflow you will likely have to request your user authenticate again after an hour.

OT: Thats an impressive app you are working on if your users will be using it beyond the access token limit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [1], OAuth token maximum lifetime is 1 hour (3600 seconds) and it cannot be changed.

If your intention is that your application may continue working without having to "manually" recreate a new token, then you could try creating a session client that scopes to multiple requests, as described in the Best Practices Dialogflow reference [2]:

"To improve performance, you can use a single instance of a session client object for multiple requests. The session client reuses the same access token for as long as it is valid (typically one hour). Once it expires, the session client refreshes the access token automatically, so you don't need to recreate the session client to refresh your access token. Your request that also refreshes the access token can take an extra second or two".

Please, try this and let me know the results.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/best-practices